# Header and source files function definitions

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I have project A and project B under one solution in Visual Studio.
Project A needs to use some function of some class of project B, so in project B I have a file which contains all the header file of project B, let's call it `AllHeadersOfB.h`. This file is included in the `stdafx.h` file of project A, which is included in each class of project A.

I have a variable of type `Y` in the class `X`, where `Y` is a class of project B and `X` is a class of project A. In `X`, if I try to use some function of `Y` and this function is declared in the .h file and defined in the .cpp file I have an unresolved external link, but if the function is declared and defined in the header file this doesn't happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In particular, this answer; http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/3747990

Answer (score 1):

Including the headers is not enough. I guess project `B` is a library, so your project `A` needs to link to this library so that it can access the implementation of the class/function from `B`.